# Using Windows subsystem for Linux in Sublime

Tags: windows, bash, sublimetext3

For example, how to run "make" command in Bash instead of CMD ? I tried to write my own buildsystem "bash -c make", but sublime can't recognize commnad bash (which is added also to PATH). Thanks :)

Comment: Please post the build-system you created for this.

Comment: Can you execute `bash` from within `cmd.exe`?

Comment: Interaction between programs inside WSL and those outside is still quite a hassle, so it's not really possible. It would be great though, you might be able to use Cygwin or MSYS2 to quite some extend though. Would be great if you would report back how it went.